# Deleting all duplicate records except the first record in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there are a number of duplicate rows across all columns (there is no `autoincrement ID / primary key` column). I want to keep the first record of the duplicate and delete all others.

Some of the columns will have null values.

I have tried the following syntax:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `volume_data_required`    
ADD UNIQUE INDEX ('category_desc', 'country_english_desc', 'SKUID', 'mrdr_desc', 'month_id', 'Sum_of_volume_tonnes', 'Sum_of_volume_cases', 'volume_units', 'Sum_of_gross_sales_value', 'Sum_of_turnover', 'Sum_of_gross_profit');
```

However, I am receiving an error `1064`.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and th expected  result

Comment: if you have no primary key or i you cant get the correct order to find the first record

Comment: On what basis you're going to decide which record is first? Do you have any timestamp field to decide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER IGNORE TABLE is not longer available in MySQL 5.7 as it causes replication issues.
https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395

I would suggest adding a numeric auto-increment PK field to table, to help with finding the first row.  (Primary keys are critical for performance, so perhaps consider it long term too.)

Step 1:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD pkCol INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment FIRST;
```

Step 2:

Write a subquery to find the first Primary Key, grouping by all the fields that would make the row duplicate.  Then you can delete all rows in the outer query that join on the fields but don't match the first PK.

If the column that you are joining to may be NULL, you will need to wrap the column with an IFNULL as you cannot JOIN on NULL fields.  Similarly, you cannot group on a NULL field in the GROUP BY clause, and need to wrap the column in IFNULL.

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl t1
JOIN (
   SELECT t2.*, MIN(pkCol) first_pkCol
   FROM tbl t2
   GROUP BY IFNULL(col1,0),col2,col3
) t2 ON (IFNULL(t1.col1,0) = IFNULL(t2.col1,0)
         AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 
         AND t1.col3 = t2.col3)
WHERE t1.pkCol <> t2.first_pkCol;
```